# Is there a word for deeper, more abstract, layer of truth?

Tags: metaphysics

https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-bcc3f8c0684a7a470d2e69f89990b02a

Is there a word for deeper, more abstract, layer of truth? In computer science, we have this term called abstraction layer that refers to different level of abstractions, and I was wondering if in metaphysics there were similar terms or concepts used to refer to what might be underneath the material world we perceive. I am not talking of scale, molecule scale, atomic scale, quantum scale, etc, but different level of reality itself, something more abstract or deeper than the material world where molecules, atoms and quantum particles reside.

Comment: [First principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_principle#Aristotle's_contribution) or foundations.

Comment: Abstract layer of TRITH? What does that mean?  There basically are two categories at the end of the day: objective truths and contingent truths.  All truths will fall under one of these. Neither one is based on your perception or awareness of truth. Objective truth is something independently true & CONSTANTLY TRUE with or without you or your awareness to it. Time frame is irrelevant here.  Contingent truth, on the other hand, is relevant to time & NEVER CONSTANT. That is, x can be true today & that same x is false next week. Contingent truths are temporary. Objective truth is permanent.

Comment: In Buddhism there are [two levels of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_truths_doctrine), conventional (*saṁvṛti*) about appearances, the *maya*, and ultimate (*paramārtha*) about the underlying reality. In the West something like that is reproduced in Kant's distinction between phenomenal and noumenal knowledge, but his noumenal is completely inaccessible to us. The [double truth doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averroism#Averroism_and_scholasticism), often misascribed to Averroes, can also be interpreted in a similar vein, plain one for the commoners, higher one for the learned.

Answer (score 1):

*"...what might be underneath the material world we perceive"?*

In Heidegger's terminology, the word you are look for actually *is* 'truth'.  In contrast, the *appearance* of the world is [Aletheia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aletheia#Heidegger_and_aletheia) :-

> Heidegger ... wrote that "*Aletheia*, disclosure regarded as the
> opening of presence, is not yet truth. Is *aletheia* then less than
> truth? Or is it more because it first grants truth as *adequatio* and
> *certitudo*, because there can be no presence and presenting outside of
> the realm of the opening?"

See also [Contributions to Philosophy (of the Event), 236. Truth](https://books.google.gg/books?id=nMupXLZd8s4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA290#v=onepage&q&f=false)